# C# How to revert changes in a dialog with the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mvvm-light

First of I'm a java developer, currently helping with a C# project so keep that in mind while answering.

I have the following scenario.  I have a datagrid with records and when I double click I open a new window(dialog) with some fields and a save and cancel button.  I want the cancel button to revert all changes done in the dialog.

I would say this to be a very common scenario, yet I have to find one single answer on stackoverflow that actually works and doesn't require a gazillion lines of boilerplate code.  I'm not going to paste my entire project here and I'll try to put the relevant code available

Galaxy and SelectedJob are simple JSON objects that are serializable and have getters and setters nothing more.  an example. Job.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GalaxyCreator.Model.Json
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Job
    {
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Boolean StartActive { get; set; }
        public Boolean Disabled { get; set; }
        public Boolean Rebuild { get; set; }
        public Boolean Commandeerable { get; set; }
        public Boolean Subordinate { get; set; }
        public bool Buildatshipyard { get; set; } = true;
        public JobLocation JobLocation { get; set; }
        public JobCategory JobCategory { get; set; }
        public JobQuota JobQuota { get; set; }
        public IList<JobOrder> Orders { get; set; }
        public String Basket { get; set; }
        public String Encounters { get; set; }
        public String Time { get; set; }
        public Ship Ship { get; set; }
        public IList<String> Subordinates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my viewmodel of the datagrid form.

```
using System.Windows;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using GalaxyCreator.Dialogs.DialogFacade;
using GalaxyCreator.Model.Json;

namespace GalaxyCreator.ViewModel
{
    class JobEditorViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private IDialogFacade dialogFacade = null;
        private RelayCommand<object> _jobEditorDetailClickedCommand;

        public Galaxy Galaxy { get; set; }
        public Job SelectedJob { get; set; }

        public JobEditorViewModel(Galaxy Galaxy)
        {
            this.Galaxy = Galaxy;
            this.dialogFacade = new DialogFacade();
        }

        public RelayCommand<object> JobEditorClickedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_jobEditorDetailClickedCommand == null)
                {
                    _jobEditorDetailClickedCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((param) => JobEditorClicked(param));
                }

                return _jobEditorDetailClickedCommand;
            }
        }

        private void JobEditorClicked(object param)
        {
            Dialogs.DialogService.DialogResult result = this.dialogFacade.ShowJobEditorDetail("Job Editor Detail", param as Window, this.SelectedJob);           
        }
    }
}
```

The view for this viewmodel

```
<UserControl x:Class="GalaxyCreator.View.JobEditorView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GalaxyCreator.View"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:GalaxyCreator.Model.JobEditor"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
             xmlns:cmd ="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"            
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="1500">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto">
                <Label Content="Job Editor" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGrid x:Name="JobDataGrid" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Galaxy.Jobs}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedJob, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="500">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JobId" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JobName" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=JobEditorClickedCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Following are a bunch of classes that will open the dialog and do some boilerplate to get the response from the dialog etc ... they are not important I hope for this question so I leave them out and go straight to the viewmodel of the dialog form.  I've been reading a bunch about the memento pattern and keeping a deep clone of the original object somewhere and on cancel put it back.  This sounded to me like the most clean solution available.  There seem to be a dozen more like updatemode explicit or something ... and then usually followed by 10000 lines of why this isn't supported with MVVM

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using GalaxyCreator.Dialogs.DialogService;
using GalaxyCreator.Model.Json;
using System.Windows;

    namespace GalaxyCreator.Dialogs.JobEditor
    {
        class JobEditorDetailViewModel : DialogViewModelBase
        {
            private JobEditorDetailMemento memento;
            public Job Job { get; set; }

            private RelayCommand<object> _saveCommand = null;
            public RelayCommand<object> SaveCommand
            {
                get { return _saveCommand; }
                set { _saveCommand = value; }
            }

            private RelayCommand<object> _cancelCommand = null;
            public RelayCommand<object> CancelCommand
            {
                get { return _cancelCommand; }
                set { _cancelCommand = value; }
            }

            private JobOrder _selectedOrder;
            public JobOrder SelectedOrder
            {
                get { return _selectedOrder; }
                set
                {
                    if (_selectedOrder == value)
                        return;
                    _selectedOrder = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedOrder");
                }
            }

            public JobEditorDetailViewModel(string message, Job job) : base(message)
            {
                this.memento = new JobEditorDetailMemento(job);
                this.Job = job;
                this._saveCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((parent) => OnSaveClicked(parent));
                this._cancelCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((parent) => OnCancelClicked(parent));
            }

            private void OnSaveClicked(object parameter)
            {
                this.CloseDialogWithResult(parameter as Window, DialogResult.Yes);
            }

            private void OnCancelClicked(object parameter)
            {
                this.Job.Id = memento.Job.Id;
                this.CloseDialogWithResult(parameter as Window, DialogResult.No);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the abbreviated xaml code for this detail view

```
<UserControl x:Class="GalaxyCreator.Dialogs.JobEditor.JobEditorDetailView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GalaxyCreator.Dialogs.JobEditor"
      xmlns:model="clr-namespace:GalaxyCreator.Model.Json"
      xmlns:util="clr-namespace:GalaxyCreator.Util"    
      xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"             
      mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="600">

    <Grid Margin="4">
        <Label Content="Id" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Job.Id, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
        <Label Content="Name" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Job.Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Grid.Column="3" x:Name="name" />

            <Button Name="btnSubmit" Content="Save" 
                Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"  Margin="0,0,0,5"/>

            <Button Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" 
                Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

See the thing is this is actually working to a point.  As you can see I'm only testing with the id property.  When I press cancel the dialog closes and in memory the property has changed.  If I doubleclick the same row on my datagrid the dialog opens with the old value.  HOWEVER ... the property on the datagrid HAS changed.  So in the datagrid you see my new typed id, while in memory it contains the old one.  I need a way to signal my datagrid hey ... please do an update the property has changed.

So the big question is:

- can I get away with this what is probably a hack and not MVVM clean (and to be frank after all these hours on this, I'm starting to not care anymore)
- is there a way to signal the datagrid to "render" once more with the new data in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, which I believe essentially answers everything that you have asked, you use PropertyChanged event of the class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface to signal the change that should be rendered.

It seems that you are using some package that is using RaisePropertyChanged method to do what I said above. Currently you are calling it on just one setter so you need to implement it on more places.

Comment: Well yes but this is a property on the ViewModel of my editor detail.  If I have to do what you mention here.  I would have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on all my JSON objects.  They are just dumb setter and getter objects that are serializable.  I'll add my Job object to the question for clarity

Comment: @kenny out of box there is no solution for that. However, you may try FoddyWeavers package so that every public property that implements get and set also raises PropertyChanged. But in general you have to do that there is no other way just you may use some tricks like that package that will generate that code for you in the back.

Comment: @kenny - also not sure what your undo should exactly do, but you may create a new collection that replicates the current collection if it changes and then raise the property collection changed. Also if it is ObservableCollection there is one method to force the redraw.

Comment: I tried the ObservableCollection idea.  There is an ObservableCollection of Job on the Galaxy JSON.  It used to be just a IList.  However that didn't work, ofcourse Galaxy does not implement any interface ... maybe if I let it implement INotification.  I would have to try

Comment: As said you can create a new IList based on your current List and raise property changed. If it does the trick for you it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well as answered by @Ivan Ičin after implementing the interface it worked however translated to MVVM Light this became

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GalaxyCreator.Model.Json
{
    public class Job : ObservableObject
    {
        private String _id;
        public String Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _id, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also ObservableObject is NOT Serializable !!!  So if you clone your objects with the tried method of serializing and then instantiating a new object with that string it can't work.  I used a json hack to get it going , prob not the cleanest solution but since I was working with json anyhow ... why not ...

```
public static T CloneJson<T>(T source)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source));
}
```

I'm glad I got it to work so thnx Ivan, but I'm severely disappointed in the amount of boilerplate I have to add to my simple as we would call it in java POJO objects.  I understand the mentioned package FoddyWeavers that is codeweaving the boilerplate around the setters much like AspectJ in Java.  However this was an extra layer of complexity I didn't feel like adding to this what is essentially a simple application.  Show a datagrid, open a form in a dialog, edit stuff with the option for cancelling the edits.

C# being said as the easier solution to make fast form application has sofar not convinced or impressed me as a java dev.  I would have been faster done in JSF or JSP and that is ancient tech